# Is there a list of all Scala compilation error message?

Tags: scala

I would like to learn all compilation errors. It'd great if there's some website that lists all compilation error.

Comment: You should be able to find all errors in the source code here - https://github.com/scala/scala For a second, assume if there is a website that gives you all the compilation errors, do you really think you can make sense of all those by just looking at the error messages and not the source code that lead to those compilation errors?

Comment: yes, it would be a great learning resource if there's a list of compilation error with examples and elaborate explanations. Could you point to specific place in github.com/scala/scala? For @JohanS, I'm not sure if we should start a debate around which way of learning is more effective for whom here. It looks like a separate discussion. Thanks!

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta nvm, I've found it https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/ContextErrors.scala Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @Tanin please tell me what you will learn from that, I usually learn which errors I make when I write that kind of code. Take for example macro compiler errors, if you are writing macros you will see what's wrong with the code through the compiler error messages. Trying to find your own bugs through scanning the compiler code is hardcore.